# starting openhab after beagle bone reboot

Tags: beagleboneblack, reboot, openhab

I am following this tuto to start openhab after beagle bone reboot:

http://tuxtec.blogspot.fr/2013/11/installing-openhab-on-beaglebone-black.html
 ($4. Autostart OpenHAB)

but It is not working, I got the following error:

```
root@beaglebone:~# systemctl status openhab.service
openhab.service - OpenHAB
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openhab.service; enabled)
      Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri, 29 May 2015 12:26:39 +0200; 17s ago
     Process: 1812 ExecStart=/usr/local/OpenHab1.7/start.sh (code=exited, status=127)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/openhab.service
```

my beagle bone operating system is: "Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
any ideas why?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

OpenHAB 1.7 (current as of this writing) has an apt-repo so that you can easily install the OpenHAB code and addons as one would install all software on Debian.  Please follow [these instructions for Beaglebone Black](https://github.com/openhab/openhab/wiki/Hardware-FAQ#cubieboard-odroid-beaglebone-black), which continue with the [generic instructions](https://github.com/openhab/openhab/wiki/Linux---OS-X#apt-get) for all Linux and OSX installations.  When new stable releases come out, you will only have to

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

in order to stay current.